# Error: Invariant Violation: Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component stack

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm having hard time to cope up with this error.

[image: Touchable child setNativeProps error]

I don't understand why ? I have a child component that is not using custom component. I wrapped the `Text` or `Image` or `Icon` in a `View` component and then wrapped them in `TouchableHighlight` still getting the error on a particular page but not on other pages which are doing the same thing.

```
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={this.changeTo} style={PictureStyles.btnClickContain}
      underlayColor='#042417'>
      <View
        style={PictureStyles.btnContainer}>
        <Icon
          name='fontawesome|calendar'
          size={25}
          color='#042'
          style={PictureStyles.btnIcon}/>
        <Text style={PictureStyles.btnText}>Book</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to fix a similar error in my app by following the instructions in the docs about [Composite components and setNativeProps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#composite-components-and-setnativeprops) to forward `setNativeProps` to a child. From the docs:

> All we need to do is provide a setNativeProps method on our component that calls setNativeProps on the appropriate child with the given arguments.

Below is your code updated with the same changes the worked for me. I was also using `react-native-icons` as it looks like you are too.

The only changes are the `setNativeProps` method and creating a `ref` on the `View` using the [`ref` callback syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  setNativeProps (nativeProps) {
    this._root.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={this.changeTo} style={PictureStyles.btnClickContain}
        underlayColor='#042417'>
        <View
          ref={component => this._root = component}
          style={PictureStyles.btnContainer}>
          <Icon
            name='fontawesome|calendar'
            size={25}
            color='#042'
            style={PictureStyles.btnIcon}/>
          <Text style={PictureStyles.btnText}>Book</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: In my case it crashes immediately if I have `Icon` element there and start typing. If I remove it, everything works fine for a while and then crashes as well :/